Помогите сделать таблицу html
Помогите сделать подобную таблицу в  html: 

Для создания такой таблицы в HTML с разным размером ячеек можно использовать   с объединёнными ячейками (атрибуты rowspan и colspan)


<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Большая ячейка 1</td>
        <td>Ячейка 2</td>
        <td>Ячейка 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ячейка 4</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Ячейка 5</td>
        <td colspan="2">Ячейка 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        
        <td rowspan="2">Ячейка 7</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Ячейка 8</td>
        <td>Ячейка 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Ячейка 10</td>
        <td>Ячейка 11</td>
    </tr>
</table>




не совпадает с картинкой

Помогите пожалуйста

Код не совпадает с таблицей

я поправила(:
Но вроде направление было исчерпывающим?
